# How can I make my formGroup default back to [ngValue]="null"?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working with Reactive Forms in Angular 6. I have a FormGroup that has a numerous select dropdown inputs. Each one has a default value if the user hasn't selected anything yet. These inputs are not required and the user may skip many of them if they are not applicable. After the user makes their selection and hit's the search button the values from the dropdown inputs are then added to the url via the router.navigate().

When the user navigates back to the page those values appear again via the route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get() in my ngOnInit() which is what I want. However, if the user skips any of the select inputs instead of showing the default value the select inputs show up blank. What I expected was the default value to show up again. I can see by console logging the providerForm object it's returning back everything as I'm expecting, but it doesn't look like the null is binding back to the [ngValue] How can I fix this?

Below is the relevant code. My [formGroup]="providerForm" is on the top level form element not shown below.

```
<section class="results__filters__section card">
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <p class="t-title t-bold">Specialty</p>
                    <div class="input input--select u-fillRemaining">
                        <select formControlName="specialty">
                            <option [ngValue]="null">Select Specialty</option>
                            <option [value]="speciality" *ngFor="let speciality of options.specialities">{{speciality}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <p class="t-title t-bold">Language</p>
                    <div class="input input--select u-fillRemaining">
                        <select formControlName="language">
                            <option [ngValue]="null">Select Language</option>
                            <option [value]="language" *ngFor="let language of options.languages">{{language}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <p class="t-title t-bold">Gender</p>
                    <div class="input input--select u-fillRemaining">
                        <select formControlName="gender">
                            <option [ngValue]="null">Select Gender</option>
                            <option [value]="gender" *ngFor="let gender of options.gender">{{gender}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <p class="t-title t-bold">Distance</p>
                    <div class="input input--select u-fillRemaining">
                        <select formControlName="distance">
                            <option [ngValue]="null">Select Distance</option>
                            <option [value]="distance" *ngFor="let distance of options.distance">{{distance}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <p class="t-title t-bold">Hospital Affiliation</p>
                    <div class="input input--select u-fillRemaining">
                        <select formControlName="affiliation">
                            <option [ngValue]="null">Select Hospital</option>
                            <option [value]="affiliation" *ngFor="let affiliation of options.affiliation">{{affiliation}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
</section>
```

// component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.specialtyQuery = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('specialty');
    this.languageQuery = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('language');
    this.genderQuery = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('gender');
    this.distanceQuery = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('distance');
    this.affiliationQuery = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('affiliation');
    this.primaryCareQuery = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('primaryCare');
    this.accomodationsQuery = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('accomodations');
    this.newPatientsQuery = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('newPatients');

    this.providerForm = this.fb.group({
        specialty: this.specialtyQuery || null,
        language: this.languageQuery || null,
        gender: this.genderQuery || null,
        distance: this.distanceQuery || null,
        affiliation: this.affiliationQuery || null,
        primaryCare: this.primaryCareQuery || '',
        accomodations: this.accomodationsQuery || '',
        newPatients: this.newPatientsQuery || ''
    });

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a StackBlitz for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it and I get the same thing when I try to match "null" in the `<select>`. So a null of type string. However when I assign the value of null (not a string) it works.

I see in your console that the values are "null" as in of type string.

Can you see if this works.

try to assign `null` instead of `"null"`

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but changing the assignment to just null doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: I'm going to try and create a check that doesn't pass the value to the queryParameter unless it was changed.

Comment: Am I correct when I think that your `this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('affiliation');` return value `"null"` and  when you check here `affiliation: this.affiliationQuery || null`. You return `this.affiliationQuery` and not `null` because it is populated with `"null"`. Maybe you could check if your queryParamMap returns "null" and populate it with `null` instead. (I really hope I make myself clear enough :) )

Comment: It's clear, but making that change has no affect on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value `null` in `affiliation: this.affiliationQuery || null`, but your html option value is `"null"` which is in string `<option [ngValue]="null">Select Specialty</option>`

So either change `null to "null" in ts` file or `"null" to null in html` file.

Comment: I thought that as well, but changing it has no affect.